# Bad representation of the y-values on plot R

Tags: r, plot

Let df be the following data frame

```
df
   Xvariable  Yvariable
4         P1  1177
5         P2  3127
6         P3  1426
7         P4  2291
8         P5  2404
9         P6  2857
10        P7  1347
```

I want to plot Yvariable versus Xvariable with bars. Here is what I did:

```
plot(df[, "BB"], xaxt="n", type="h", lwd=60, yaxs="i", col=palette("R3"), lend=2, ylim = c(0, 3500)),
```

here is what it gives :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIBwO.png)

You can clearly see that the red bar representing the value of 3127 is close to 3500. The same goes for the black 1177, which exceeds 1500.

Can someone explain to me what I missed?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I made a mistake, plot(df[, "Yvariable], ...) this is what I wanted to write

Comment: `?barplot`. …..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative with `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Xvariable, y = Yvariable, fill = Xvariable) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chamkrai for the elegant solution (I press that answer my question) but I still don't understand why plot produces this bad result.

Answer (score 1):

As @IRTFM points out in comments: Use `barplot`:

Base `R`:

```
barplot(df$Yvariable, names.arg = df$Xvariable, 
        xlab = "Xvariable", 
        ylab = "Yvariable", 
        main = "My title", 
        col = c("red", "blue", "gold"))
legend("topright", c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7"), fill = c("red", "blue", "gold"))
```

[image]